# How to store a array into a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm receiving data from a server in the form of an array, which I'm storing in a variable; the data is arriving every 5 seconds, so I need to store every array that comes through the server into an array.

So the array looks like this:

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM1Fd.png)

It's saved in a variable, and I'm setting it to log every 5 seconds, so all the different data is getting logged.

So I need to get it stored in an array. This is the variable from which the array is coming; here is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = this.responseText;
            snifferOnServer(myObj);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.43.154/wifimac', true);
    xhr.send();
}, 7000);

function snifferOnServer(x) {
    let obj = x.split(']');
    // console.log(obj);
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        mac = obj[i];
        macIdData = mac.split(',');
        console.log(macIdData);
    }
}
```

The array I was seeing in the console was getting through macIdData. I need to store all of the data in a new array The macIdData is a 2 dimensional array.

Thank You.

Need to store a variable which consist of array into a new array.

Comment: It looks like you're getting [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON). JS has methods for parsing JSON data directly, you don't need to parse a JSON string by yourself.

Comment: If I understand you correctly and you want to add the received data to the array, then instead of reassigning `macIdData = ...` you could use `Array.prototype.push(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this out. Also it's best to use JavaScript methods to parse your data-set.

```js
// Sample of API data
let rawData = JSON.stringify([
    ["1234", "45678", "9"],
    ["abc", "def", "ghi"],
    ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
])

snifferOnServer(rawData);

function snifferOnServer(data) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(data);
    let macIdData = [];

    // Loop through the obj dataset
    obj.forEach((mac) => {
        // Loop through the mac dataset
        mac.forEach((items) => {
            // store each value in the mac Array
            macIdData.push(items);
        })
    });

    console.log(macIdData);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

*Editing because i accidentally pressed submit

array = [...array, yourArray]

```js
let array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  array = [...array, [1,2,3,4,5]];
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: so is it ready i am not understand this ..

Comment: Essentially this is only how to store array into an array. What you also need is an array that is declared before setInterval in which you will store data

Comment: 0
: 
Array(3)
0
: 
"B2104895"
1
: 
"59"
2
: 
"131"
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)

Comment: Thanks worked for me ...But I have question this array storing 3 values So how can i for loop this array to get all the data ??

Comment: Declare your variable outside function and interval. If you declare it inside any of them, they will be redeclared every time your interval/function runs